# getting localhost - / when browsing IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm new in asp.net and just finish building my project. So I decided to publish the website to over local network in my office. However, I'm getting error to connect the localDB. I've tried many tutorials but it won't work for me.

[this is my configuration in IIS Manager and I'm sure the physical path is right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hdYr.png)

[when I browsing the website I'm getting this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09HkA.png)

[so i decide to click the .aspx file and i'am getting this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Yuk.png)

It seems like my Database not connected. How can I solve this? I've tried installing SQL Server Management Studio and run the database into it but still the same.

this is my connection string in web.config

````
    <add name="uploadConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>```
````

Comment: LocalDB is meant for development. When you really host a web site for production, switch to a true SQL Server instance, and revise your connection string.

Comment: I think the problem is your connection string is trying to connect local sql db which is installed by Visual studio. And I remembered it has priority to load .mdf. So Please ensure the db can be accessed and try to remove mdf file from your connection string.

Comment: i've solve the problem. The problem is i don't have the local db server. So i'am installing SqlLocalDB that i have downloaded on this article [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) and now it's working fine. Thanks